# How to show name in dropdown and not in the selected value in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

This is my code to fetch item from firebase and show in dropdown list.. Dropdown value contains only the dial code .. the flag and country name are only for display and not used for further storage in firebase

```
   `import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stract/utils/custom_config.dart';

class DialCodeDropdown extends StatefulWidget {
  ValueNotifier dialCodeNotifier;
  DialCodeDropdown({required this.dialCodeNotifier});

  @override
  State<DialCodeDropdown> createState() => DialCodeDropdownState();
}

class DialCodeDropdownState extends State<DialCodeDropdown> {
  String dropdownvalue = "61";

  String urlImages = "";
  List<String> dialCode = [];
  List<String> countryCode = [];

  List<Map> codeAndImage = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("Inside Init State");
    fetchDialCodeFromCollections();
    // dropdownvalue = dialCode.first;
    widget.dialCodeNotifier.value = dropdownvalue;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 20,
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        underline: SizedBox(),
        value: dropdownvalue,
        icon: VerticalDivider(
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        items: codeAndImage.map((Map map) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: map["dialCode"].toString(),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Image.network(
                  map["image"],
                  width: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text(map["country"].toString()),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text("+ ${map["dialCode"].toString()}"),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          print(newValue);
          setState(() {
            dropdownvalue = newValue!;
            widget.dialCodeNotifier.value = newValue;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future fetchImagesFromFirestore(path) async {
    try {
      await FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child(path)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          urlImages = value;
        });
      });
      return urlImages;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchDialCodeFromCollections() async {
    var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .doc("${CustomConfig.FS_MASTER_DATA}/CountryCodes")
        .get();
    data.exists
        ? {
            data.data()!.forEach((key, value) async {
              if (value["isActive"] == true) {
                await fetchImagesFromFirestore("/Country-Flags/$key.jpg")
                    .then((Element) {
                  setState(() {
                    codeAndImage.add({
                      "dialCode": value["DialCode"].toString(),
                      "country": value["Country"],
                      "image": Element.toString()
                    });
                  });
                });
                setState(() {
                  countryCode.add(key);

                  if (dialCode.contains(value["DialCode"]) != true)
                    dialCode.add(value["DialCode"]);
                });
              }
            })
          }
        : print("no data");
  }
}
```

`

The output is as follows :
[image]
But I want the following output..
[image]

How to achieve this? (show the country name in the dropdown value but not in the selected value )

UPDATE:

This is the output I am getting from the below answer[image]

Comment: Try this package :- https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_field

Comment: This package gives a list of countries and their dial code. But I want to take the code and flag from the firebase .. Because at this point I want to display only 2 countries and in future I will add some more.. Is there any way to do this without this package ? @HarshSureja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `selectedItemBuilder` to solve this,

Your code should be as following for `selectedItemBuilder`

```
selectedItemBuilder: (context) =>codeAndImage.map((Map map) {
      return Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Image.network(
              map["image"],
              width: 20,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Text("+ ${map["dialCode"].toString()}"),
          ],
        );
    }).toList()
```

**Edited**
I used `DropdownButton2` to make two different width for display and list with `dropdownWidth`.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 20,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2<String>(
          value: dropdownvalue,
          dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                blurRadius: 6,
                spreadRadius: 2,
                offset: Offset(0, 4),
              )
            ],
          ),
          selectedItemBuilder: (context) => codeAndImage.map((Map map) {
            return Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Image.network(
                  map["image"],
                  width: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 5,
                ),
                Text("+ ${map["dialCode"].toString()}"),
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
          icon: VerticalDivider(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          dropdownWidth: 150,
          items: codeAndImage.map((Map map) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: map["dialCode"].toString(),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    map["image"],
                    width: 20,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Text(map["country"].toString()),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 5,
                  ),
                  Text("+ ${map["dialCode"].toString()}"),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            print(newValue);
            setState(() {
              dropdownvalue = newValue!;
              widget.dialCodeNotifier.value = newValue;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Still I can't take the width with the list content.

Comment: This works good. But there is a renderflex in the dropdown as it is not expanding based on the country name.. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: Can you attach the output and expected from that

Comment: I have updated my question with the current output.. I want the same in proper format without renderflex

Comment: I tried to fix it with DropDown but no luck, can you try with https://pub.dev/packages/fl_country_code_picker

Comment: I am instructed not to use any package :( But thank you so much for your effort

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenient. Can you try with custom code by using `DropDownMenu`, here you may reach your requirement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252021/discussion-between-sindu-and-alex-sunder-singh).